# How to make Object Properties flexible with Zod?

Tags: node.js, typescript, schema, zod, trpc.io

New to Typescript, Zod & Trpc.

Say I have a schema for both animals & plants. I want to store all their common properties in the "root" of the schema and then put the more specific properties into a sub-object called `custom`. (just a made-up example to simplify things)

So far I have this:

```
create: t.procedure
    .input(z.object({
      id: z.string(),
      type: z.string(), //can be "ANIMAL" or "PLANT"
      //all other common properties go here
      //...
      custom: z.object({ fur: z.string() }) //...if it's an animal, it will have "fur" here, if it's a plant something entirely different, like "seeds"
    }).nullish())
```

I don't understand how to get this to work, or how I would accomplish this with zod. I looked into zods discriminated union, but I don't seem to fully understand how the syntax works?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of when you would use [`discriminatedUnion`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#discriminated-unions).

For example:

```js
const inputSchema = z.discriminatedUnion("type", [
  z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    type: z.literal('ANIMAL'),
    custom: z.object({ fur: z.string() }),
  }),
  z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    type: z.literal('PLANT'),
    custom: z.object({ seeds: z.number() }),
  })
]).nullish();
```

You could then pass that schema into `input()`. If you have a lot of shared fields, you could store those in a base schema which you would `merge` in once rather than duplicating them in each branch.